# JetBrains TypeScript inspector & d.ts references

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Have a TypeScript project that compiles by Grunt.

Also I'm using JetBrains WebStorm as IDE and its' TypeScript inspector.

The problem - that it's working incorrectly with included

```
<reference path="Declarations.d.ts" />
```

That reference is required for the Grunt compilation, but inspector don't recognize it as definitions, and I got a tons of errors as they placed in d.ts and on the TS module:

> Duplicate identifier ClassName

How can it be resolved?

Tried to use tsconfig file, but isn't possible to use it in my case.

Comment: what errors do you see namely? Looks like your `Declarations.d.ts` file is respected, but the compiler is confused by declarations there that duplicate declarations from TypeScript default `*lib.d.ts` files

Comment: @lena I got a "Duplicate identifier" errors for each of my project classnames. E.g. classnames / modules have a definitions in Definitions.d.ts to allow grunt compile TS w/o needed classes by the reference directive, and belong it - Webstorm for some reasons uses "reference" directive as TS including, and gives me a Duplicate identifier error (I have excluded .d.ts in the tsconfig.json, but as it exists on reference - WebStorm still sees it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstorm uses `<reference path>` directive for TS including, just as the compiler does:) This is the expected and perfectly valid behavior. And excluding referenced files in `tsconfig.json` doesn't indeed help, as files that are explicitly referenced from included files are also included. See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html : `Any files that are referenced by files included via the "files" or "include" properties are also included. Similarly, if a file B.ts is referenced by another file A.ts, then B.ts cannot be excluded unless the referencing file A.ts is also specified in the "exclude" list.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I understand that, but why the grunt / gulp compilers are ignoring these references? 

More precisely - it understands that d.ts is the only definition, and there aren't a "Duplicate identifier" error on their compilation.

How can I make my TS be valid for a both?

Comment: I have no idea what your Grunt configuration looks like - most probably, it uses its own way to include files in compilation. Please share a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: Don't know the best way to share it, but here's a Dropbox link for the sample project. - https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu5l8erh1oe7855/TS%20test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Probably, the problem that the WebStorm identifies all ts files as one project while Grunt compiles it by parts. So WebStorm see a duplication.

Is there any way to provide multiple tsconfig files? Or multiple projects for the one tsconfig? To let Webstorm know which files compiles with others?

Comment: yes, you can have multiple tsconfig.json files in your project. The one nearest to the current file (when searching from its dir up to the project root folder) will be used for compilation. So, if you have duplicate identifiers declared in folder `a` and `b`, create separate tsconfig.json files in these folders - they will be treated as separate typescript projects by compiler

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally resolved that issue. Created tsconfig for the each bundle, and probably will go out from the Grunt TS configuration to tsconfigs in the project, to be clear with it in any situation